# Attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-functions, webdeploy, .net-6.0

I'm getting this error window message while trying to deploy a .NET 6 **Azure Functions** app to Azure from Visual Studio 2022:

> Publish has encountered an error. We
> were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log
> for more details.
>
> A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
> "C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEB87.tmp"

The `tmpEB87.tmp` file contents look like this:

```
2/16/2022 1:43:18 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 

===================
```

The Output log says this:

> The attempt to publish the ZIP file through
> https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP
> status code Forbidden.

The `MyFunctionName - Zip Deploy.pubxml` file contents looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>ZipDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://xxx.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>False</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/some-random-letters-123456789/resourceGroups/my-resource-group-name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MyFunctionName</ResourceId>
    <UserName>$MyFunctionName</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <IsLinux>true</IsLinux>
    <PublishUrl>https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/</PublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I've already spent a ton of time on this, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

One of the workarounds that you can try is to create a new Publish profile and publish it again. For this navigate to Your project's directory -> Properties -> Publish Profiles and delete the contents (or you can move to another location). Finally, click Finish in the publish profile wizard again.

[image]

[image]

---

Make sure `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is 1 from your Application settings. Also, try restarting your function app.

[image]

[image]

**NOTE:-** When deploying from Visual Studio, you should be asked whether you want to upgrade the version of the app that is currently deployed. If you say yes, your app will be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions package is updated to the latest version.