# Publish fails for Azure Func Isolated

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-deployment

**Trying to deploy Isolated Azure Func from VS2022
I already created brand new func in Azure portal and scaffolded new function in VS2022
Func works locally. I am deploying using consumption plan and to windows**

Getting this when publishing:

```
Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
"C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA19A.tmp"
```

Nothing helpful in tmpEB87.tmp:

```
3/8/2024 7:38:58 PM
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 

===================
```

Output log:

```
2>A publish profile with the name 'ZipDeploy' was not found in the project. Set the PublishProfile property to a valid file name.
2>WorkerExtensions -> C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\farqnhib.ee0\publishout\
2>Publishing C:\Temp\isolated\app\obj\Release\net6.0\PubTmp\isolated - 20240308193855433.zip to https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy...
2>The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden.
```

ZipDeploy.pubxml file contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121.
-->
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>ZipDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://MYSITE.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>false</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/MY_SUBSCRIPTION/resourceGroups/MY_GROUP/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/MY_SITE</ResourceId>
    <UserName>$mysite1</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
    <PublishUrl>https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/</PublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My func project file: isolated.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <RootNamespace>isolated_test_app</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.22.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I already tried:

- disabling/enabling ftp/scm access in func settings
- updating VS2022 to latest
- checking all logs - on scm also, nothing helpfull
- setting WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE to 0 and then back to 1
- installing/updating azure-cli and azure core tools
- adding publish profile directly from wizard and downloading/adding to VS from Azure Portal
- Check the path to solution, found one advice to remove spaces in path (my path to func: C:\Temp\isolated)
- Renamed publish profile - remove all spaces in name (my name: ZipProfile.pubxml)
- Update all func packages/dependencies to latest version
- Removed WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE in azure portal, reset publish profile, then restarted Func App, then removed profile from VS2022, connected from VS2022 to azure and loaded new publish profile - did not help
- Started VS2022 in administrator mode

My current settings in configuration:
[image: config]

By the way I am able to deploy created zip with command below using azure cli:

```
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group yourresourcegroupnameonazure --name yourfunctionappnameonazure --src xxx.zip
```

None-isolated (in-process) function deploys successfully
Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Remove `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting, refresh the function app. Also remove the existing publish profile in visual studio, create a new one and deploy.

Comment: Thanks for helping. Did not help. Removed WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE in azure portal, reset publish profile, then restarted Func App, then removed profile from VS2022, connected from VS2022 to azure and loaded new publish profile. I also added pic to the original post with my current variables in config

Comment: Sign-out and sign back in Visual Studio and check if the issue persists.

Comment: Issue is still there. Did not help

Comment: Did you check logs in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA19A.tmp`?

Comment: Also close the IDE completely and try again.

Comment: Yes, I checked the contents in this tmp - nothing helpful. Error is always the same - you can see it in my original post. Some generic unknown exception of type Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException. Also I closed VS after I signed out - did not help. Super weird... Happens only with isolated func deployment

Comment: By the way I am able to deploy created zip with command below using azure cli:
az webapp deployment source config-zip --resource-group yourresourcegroupnameonazure --name yourfunctionappnameonazure --src xxx.zip

Comment: Then the issue could be Visual Studio. Did you try upgrading VS version?

Comment: Yes. I am using the latest VS2022 (Professional edition)

Comment: Is it 17.8 or 17.9? Also did you try to deploy a new isolated function?

Comment: 17.9.2. Just now completely repaired VS2022 - took an hour. Created brand new isolated func, restarted everything. Still the same - The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

> The attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://MYSITE.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden.

HTTP status code 403 Forbidden indicates that the server refuses to authorize the request.

This error may occur if the credentials used to authenticate the request do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.

- Turn on Basic Auth Publishing status in the `Function App=>Configuration=>General Settings`:
- Check if you have enabled access restrictions in the function app and provide public access.

[image]

- Once the deployment fails in VS, go to the `Function app=>Functions` in portal, click on *Refresh* and *publish* again.
- Clean and re-build the solution.
- Create a new function app via Visual Studio during Publish Profile creation and deploy the function.

I have created a .NET 6 Isolated Azure function and deployed to Azure through Visual Studio.

**.csproj:**

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Application Settings of function App:**

[image]

- Created a new function through Visual Studio:

[image]

**zip Deploy.pubxml:**

```xml
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>ZipDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>AzureWebSite</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>https://<functionappname>.azurewebsites.net</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>false</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ResourceId>/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourcegroups/resourcegroupname/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/functionappname</ResourceId>
    <UserName>$functionappname</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>true</_SavePWD>
    <PublishUrl>https://functionappname.scm.azurewebsites.net/</PublishUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

- Able to deploy the function to Azure Function app (Windows) with Consumption Plan:

[image]

**Deployment Status in KUDU site:**

[image]

**References:**

[Attempt to publish the ZIP file through https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zipdeploy failed with HTTP status code Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71147966/attempt-to-publish-the-zip-file-through-https-xxx-scm-azurewebsites-net-api-zi).